# Laravel Session not working correctly and Token mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session

I have problems with TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php in `Laravel 5.2`. My session driver is set to database, I've generated session table (Laravel's standard session table - generated with: php artisan session:table).

When I switching session driver to file - everything is working normally. And I don't know why, but Laravel generates 3 new session id(in db) each time when I refresh the page.

Has anybody had this kind of problem?

Comment: If you are switching to session driver : file  remove the table which you had created for session driver:database and then try to refresh the pages I am not sure but may it helps to you.

Comment: `php artisan session:table` only generates the migration **file**. Have you actually executed the migrations?

Comment: @Jeemusu of course. I'm not newbee to do mistakes like this. Sessions worked normally till yesterday, i don't changed anything in the code.

Comment: @Ilkinium have you set the `connection` variable in `config/session.php` ?

Comment: @Jeemusu I don't think that to change this field is necessary. I'm using only one connection to db, not multi-connection. And it's enough to change driver variable in .env file.

Comment: Ever found the solution?